# Calling subclass's function from superclass based on string in PHP

Tags: php, oop

How would I do something like this:

```
<?php
    class Controller
    {
        var $ActionName;
        var $PageParameters;

        function InvokeAction()
        {
            $actionFunctionName = ucfirst($this->ActionName);

            // Call a function named $actionFunctionName
                // where $actionFunctionName is in a subclass
        }

    }
?>
```

As a bonus, I would like to trap whether that function exists first.

Comment: have you looked at __call? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (method_exists($this, $actionFunctionName))
{
    $this->$actionFunctionName();
}
```

that should do it